Requirements for invertibility of $A B A^T$ in constrainted dynamics
What are the requirements for matrix $A$ (that isn't a square matrix), so that the matrix $A B A^T$ is invertible, given that $B$ is non-singular?
Some details for the matrices:
$B$ is the $n \times n$ mass matrix that comes from euler lagrange equations of motions ($M$ in the link below). So it is:

real,
symmetric (so also hermitian) and
positive definite.

A is the jacobian of the constraints ($H$ in the link below), a $m \times n$, where $m$ is the number of constraints. It doesn't have any special properties in general.
My intuition tells me that the constraints must be linearly independent, and thus A to be full row rank, but chatgpt told me the it must be full column rank and then i could not find any relevant theorem online to verify my intuition, and i cannot prove it either.
Extra details
This came up while trying to simulate a closed chain system, that has holonomic constraints. The relevant dynamics are described here. But i want to know when a matrix of the form  $A B A^T$ that appears in these dynamics, can be safely inverted, to ensure my simulations do not break.

Also, any indication on how i could search this, because invertibility of ABA^T doesn't show me good results, but i feel like this should be a "standard" theorem, and to find it you do not need to be a mathematician.

What is the actual matrix in the link you're referring to?

Can A be a square matrix? And is B possibly Hermitian/symmetric?

If B is Hermitian, then Sylvester's theorem gives you an answer. That is, if B is Hermitian, then it is congruent to any invertible hermitian matrix with the same number of positive eigenvalues and the same number of negative eigenvalues. This would give you the existence of such an A.

added the details for the matrices @CroCo

Hint: You can write $B=CC^T$ for some invertible $C$, e.g. Cholesky decomposition.

It all depends on the rank of $A$. $C:=ABA^T$ is invertible iff $m\leq n$ and $A$ is of rank $m$ (full rank as you had guessed). The first condition is pretty intuitive, you need less constraints than degrees of freedom, mathematically, if $m>n$, then $\text{rank }C\leq n<m$.
Geometrically, you can view $A$ as an embedding of an $m$ dimension vector space, $E$, into an $n$ dimension euclidian space, $F$, whose dot product is given by $B$. By composition, $E$ inherits a symmetric, non negative bilinear form. It is positive definite iff the embedding isomorphism has a trivial kernel thanks to the positive definiteness of the dot product of $F$. Thus, you recover the fact that $C$ must be of full rank, with the added bonus that it is symmetric (obviously), positive definite as well.
Hope this helps.
